# pins on HDD/SSD enclosure

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a SAS HDD enclosure of HP server, which has a following connector:

[image: SAS HDD]

What is the purpose of this connector? One purpose is to lit the [LEDs in front of the enclosure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLRBA.jpg) . Is this the only reason for that connector?

Comment: Could you please post the specific model of the machine you pulled this from? That would greatly reduce the chances of mere conjecture being your answer.

Comment: HP ProLiant DL360 Gen9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an [HP SmartDrive Carrier](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Coffee-Coaching/Benefits-and-Features-of-HP-SmartDrive-for-HP-ProLiant-Gen8/ba-p/6791778#.V_fCVTKZMhA), available for Gen8 and newer HP ProLiant servers.

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jb_F4nIP8z8

The purpose of the new carrier design was to add some intelligence and array configuration awareness to the disk drive. This also had the aim of reducing human error in the datacenter, as some technicians could pull the incorrect disk(s) during system maintenance and repairs.

The electrical contacts you see on the carrier are used to control the LEDs and communicate drive and array status.